# Evaluating Likelihood in Bootstrap Particle Filter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matlab, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, particle-filter

I am currently struggling with an attempt to apply a bootstrap particle filter to a linear, Gaussian state-space model

$$s_t=A\,s_{t-1}+B\,\nu_t\qquad\text{( transition equation )}$$
$$\qquad z_t=C\,s_t+D\,\varepsilon_t\qquad\text{( measurement equation )}$$

where $\nu_t$ and $\varepsilon_t$ are Gaussian, serially and mutually uncorrelated and have variance-covariance matrix $I$, respectively.

Given the nature of my problem, I realize that conventional Kalman filtering methods would be more than sufficient. This is just to understand the way the particle filter works.

My (first) problem is that in every iteration there is a single particle that is assigned an importance weight of 1. While I could get around that by scaling up the variance-covariance matrix of the measurement equation, this does not help with my second problem.

In particular, I am trying to evaluate the likelihood $f(z_{1:T})$ for a given parameterization of $A,B,C,$ and $D$ such that I can run a numerical optimizer to find the parameters that maximize the likelihood. As I simulated the system, I do know the true values.

When I do all of that using the Kalman filter, it is true that for every parameter (with the other parameters fixed at their true values) the likelihood attain its peak very close to the true value.

This is not the case, when I use the particle filter. Given the fact that the Kalman filter works beautifully, and the fairly low dimensionality of my system (6-dim state), I was told that it is quite likely that my code has an error.

Therefore, I enclosed the portion of my code that seems pertinent. I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me where I am going wrong.

In a nutshell, assuming even weights (i.e. resetting weights to $1/N$ after resampling), I approximate 
$$f(z_{t+1}|z_{1:t})\approx\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf(z_{t+1}|s_{it+1})$$

Since I am only interested in the object
$$\log\,f(z_{1:T})=\sum\,\log\,f(z_{t+1}|z_{1:t})$$ 
I overwrite the filtered states in each iteration of the following piece of code and just update the likelihood.

In the following $T$ is the number of data points and $N$ is the number of particles. Coefficient and variable names are as in the equations above.

```
Q=B*B'; % vcv for the innovation of the transition equation
R=D*D'; % vcv for the innovation of the measurement equation

QT=Q';
QT=QT(:); % vectorizing transition equation vcv

Sig0= inv(eye(36)-kron(A,A))*QT(:); 
Sig0= reshape(Sig0,6,6); % uncoditional variance of state

s0=zeros(6,1); % unconditional mean of state

s=mvnrnd(s0,Sig0,N)'; % drawing N samples for initial particle cloud
v=randn(4,N,T); % innovations to propagate particle cloud

L=0; % initializing log-likelihood

for t=1:T  
    % take s from last iteration and propagate via transition equation - returns 6-by-N array 
    s=A*s+B*v(:,:,t);
    % calculate the density p(z_t|s_it) for each s_it in cloud - returns a N-by-1 vector
    for i=1:N
        p(i)=-1/2*[log(det(2*pi*R))+(z(:,t)-C*s(:,i))'*inv(R)*(z(:,t)-C*s(:,i))];
    end
    % obtain max element of p for numerically robust computations 
    pm=max(p);
    % update the log-likelihood such that at the t-th iteration lp is the sum
    % from k=1:t of the means (over i) of p(z_k|s_ik).
    % Since I take an unweighted mean, this is as if I would have made
    % weights even after resampling in the last step. 
    L=L-log(N)+pm+log(sum(exp(p-pm)));
    % calculate the importance weight
    w=exp(p-pm)./sum(exp(p-pm));
    % multinomial resampling at each step according to importance weights
    id=randsample(1:N,N,true,w);
    x_s=x_s(:,id);
end
```

I would appreciate any pointers that might help me figuring out what is wrong with my code.

Many thanks.

Comment: The log(a+b)is not log(a)+log(b).

Comment: Thanks for your message. I am afraid that I do not follow. Could you point me to the portion of my code where I have made this mistake?

Comment: i'm a little confused by your notation but I thought that the second equation was obtained from the first by taking the log on both sides. But then the right hand side would a log of a sum that you represent as the sum of logs.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not want to inundate potential readers with the details of what I am doing, so I just outlined the results I am using. The first equation is the Monte Carlo approximation of the conditional densities, and the second is just the log of the prediction error decomposition of the joint density.